# Vue JS Data not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, vue-resource

I have the following code in Vue JS V2:

```
data() {
  return {
    properties: [],
    loading: true,
    showProgressBars: true,
    debugText: 'This is start'
  }
},
methods: {
  get() {
    const success = (r) => {
      this.properties = r.data.properties
      this.loading = false
      this.debugText = 'api has returned success'
    }
    const error = (r) => {
      console.error(r)
    }

    var resourceUri = `/api/v1/properties`

    this.$http
      .get(resourceUri)
      .then(success, error)
  }
```

I don't know why the properties array is not being updated. I can see that the API is returning the properties correctly and if I debug the script in chrome, the correct data is indeed assigned to `this.properties` in the callback.

I added the `debugText` in there and it is also not updated.

```
<p>{{debugText}}</p>
```

This code has not had any changes for the pass two years and it failed today - I'm not sure whats going on here?

Comment: Please read about the [vue reactivity in depth](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) for arrays

Comment: @wittgenstein thanks for your reply. I am not adding an element to the array or changing length. This is direct assignment and should be ok?

Comment: from my understanding you initiate an empty array and fill it with your properties that are **non-reactive** from just the assignment.

Comment: The other debug text is also not updating from callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of `vue-resource` you are using. Maybe your version is old. According to [this github page](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) when you use `this.$http.get()` in version `"vue-resource": "^1.5.3"`, you must use `response.body` to get data. I am not sure that this is the reason that your code is not working, But this code works fine for me:

```html
<template>
<h1>API page</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Apicall",
  data() {
    return {
      properties: [],
      loading: true,
      showProgressBars: true,
      debugText: 'This is start'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    get() {
      const success = (r) => {
        console.log(r.body);
        this.properties = r.body
        this.loading = false
        this.debugText = 'api has returned success'
      }
      const error = (r) => {
        console.error(r)
      }

      var resourceUri = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`

      this.$http
          .get(resourceUri)
          .then(success, error)
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.get();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Maybe for your data, you should call `r.body.data.properties`, But I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using body instead and still not working. Setting the other debug text from the callback is not updating HTML as well. However, if I set debug text from within **get()**, it updates ok. Something is wrong with updating from callback. My vue resource is: "vue-resource": "^1.3.1"

Comment: I tried ```this.$forceUpdate()``` in **success(r)** and doesn't work too.

Comment: If you can, please update the version of ```vue-resource```. I think that is the easiest solution.